# Why does new Date with a string that has dashes and a leading zeron in the month return what it does?

Tags: javascript, date

Why does,

```
new Date('2014-04-16')
```

create a date object (note Apr 15, and 17:00):

```
Tue Apr 15 2014 17:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

While

```
new Date('2014-4-16')
Wed Apr 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

and

```
new Date('2014/04/16')
Wed Apr 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pajtai/5LrGX/

Noticed this in Chrome.

Is this something to do with ISO date formatting?

Comment: `new Date('2014-04-16')` returns `Wed Apr 16 2014 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` for me on chrome, which is correct for my timezone.

Comment: @KyleNeedham The question is about when you pass one digit as the month

Comment: @KyleNeedham but does, `new Date('2014-4-16')` show something else that has 00:00:00 as opposed to 01:00:00?

Comment: @PeterAjtai `new Date('2014-4-16')` returns `Wed Apr 16 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)` I'm guessing the leading zero version takes into account the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

The constructor allows the following for a string argument

> dateString
>
> String value representing a date. The string should be in a format recognized by the >Date.parse() method ([IETF-compliant RFC 2822 timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and also a version of [ISO8601](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15)).

So if it's not one of those formats, you shouldn't rely on it. Both of the formats mentioned have two digits for month and day and use dashes, not slashes

You'll notice that Firefox and IE do not allow your month without 2 digits

```
// Firefox and IE
new Date('2014-4-16').toString()
> 'Invalid Date'
```

Comment: I was looking at the allowed date formats... where does it show whether you can do yyyy/mm/dd vs yyy-mm-dd?

Comment: [Section 15.9.1.15 Date Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) It doesn't mention using slashes for the year month day